# Application Unusable logging into the GUI

Tags: linux, graphical-user-interface

which directory renders many applications unusable including into the gui if the space allocated the /tmp/ filesystem if full?

/etc/?
/bin/?
/var/?

This seems like a simple questions but I cant seem to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

It is totally dependent on the drive setup, if your /var mount and /tmp mount are on different physical drives, then if TMP fills up, /var is not affected.

If you only have one drive, if /tmp fills up, the whole system becomes unstable.

It's a good idea to store your logs on a separate drive so you can continue writing logs when other drives fill up.